# \NewDocumentEnvironment does not work somehow

Tags: xparse

Why does `\newenvironment` work but the same code does not work with `\NewDocumentEnvironment`:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\RequirePackage{booktabs}
\RequirePackage{tabularx}

\newenvironment{invoice}
%\NewDocumentEnvironment{invoice}{}
    {\par\noindent%
     \tabularx{\textwidth}{cXrr}
     \toprule[0.7pt]\textbf{Pos.} & \textbf{Beschreibung} & \textbf{Gesamtpreis} \\ 
     \toprule[0.7pt]}
    {\midrule[0.7pt]
        && \textbf{Rechnungsbetrag} & \textbf{1234} \\ \cmidrule[0.7pt]{3-4} \\ \endtabularx}

\NewDocumentCommand{\invoiceitem}{mmm}
    {#1 & #2 && #3 \\}
    
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{invoice}
        \invoiceitem{1}{Eins}{23}
    \end{invoice}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't need `\RequirePackage`, which is for packages or classes, but `\usepackage`.

Comment: @egreg How is that relevant here? In any case, I was under the impression that `\RequirePackage` did everything that `\usepackage` does.

Comment: @egreg: What is the downside of using \RequirePackage? I was under the impression that it just prevents including a package twice…

Comment: @mrCarnivore The downside is lack of consistency. There's actually no difference between the two commands, but in user space it's better to use lowercase commands, if available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in interaction between `\NewDocumentEnvironment` and `tabularx`, because the latter needs to absorb the whole contents of the environment prior to take action.

In this case the surrounding environment has to do the same.

This happens also with `align`, `gather` and similar `amsmath` environments.

Thus the solution is to use the `b` (or `+b` if you want to allow blank lines) argument specifier.

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\RequirePackage{booktabs}
\RequirePackage{tabularx}

\NewDocumentEnvironment {invoice} { +b }
{%
  \noindent%
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cXrr}
    \toprule[0.7pt]
    \textbf{Pos.} & \textbf{Beschreibung} &  & \textbf{Gesamtpreis} \\ 
    \toprule[0.7pt]
      #1
    \midrule[0.7pt]
      & & \textbf{Rechnungsbetrag} & \textbf{1234} \\ 
    \cmidrule[0.7pt]{3-4} \\ 
  \end{tabularx}
}{}

\NewDocumentCommand {\invoiceitem} { mmm }
  {#1 & #2 & & #3 \\}
    
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{invoice}
        \invoiceitem{1}{Eins}{23}
    \end{invoice}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What does the `+b` do? Also, why did you put nothing in the environment? Why does it not work with the code in environment end?

Comment: See section 1.6 of the manual http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages/xparse.pdf

Comment: This is a fine workaround but it does not answer the OP's question

Comment: @DG' I took the liberty to add a short analysis of the problem.

Comment: @mbert It's not a workaround: indeed it's ***the*** solution.

Comment: Thank you, @egreg

Comment: @egreg No argument here, I was only saying the original answer did not explain why `\NewDocumentEnvironment` does not work as expected, which is the OP’s main question

Comment: @egreg: I was under the assumption that `\NewDocumentEnvironment` works the same as `\newenvironment` with extended capabilities (e.g. that the argument(s) can also be accessed in the end-part). I guess that assumption was wrong... I also found out that `\NewDocumentCommand` behaves differently  than `\newcommand` (the former not being expandable as a feature). So they are not really the newer and only better commands but rather different ones.

Comment: @mrCarnivore The extended argument parsing abilities come at a price. It's one of the reasons why the commands are in “camel case”.